# Rank in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to use Rank in a Where Clause. Below is the code that I am intending to use

```
  Select 
   DebtorID
  ,Rank () over (partition by DebtorID order by BalanceDate) as RankBalanceDate
  ,BalanceDate
  ,Balance
  ,UnallocatedBalance
  ,Overdue
From Debtorbalances
Where Rank () Over (Partition by DebtorID order by BalanceDate) = 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

You can use a `CTE` or a subquery to do this:

Using a `CTE`:

```
with Cte AS(
    Select 
        DebtorID
        ,rank() over (partition by DebtorID order by BalanceDate) as RankBalanceDate
        ,BalanceDate
        ,Balance
        ,UnallocatedBalance
        ,Overdue
    From Debtorbalances
)
select * 
from Cte
where 
    RankBalanceDate = 1
```

Using a subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        DebtorID
        ,rank() over (partition by DebtorID order by BalanceDate) as RankBalanceDate
        ,BalanceDate
        ,Balance
        ,UnallocatedBalance
        ,Overdue
    From Debtorbalances
)t
where 
    RankBalanceDate = 1
```